# Master-Detail Display with Sorting

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have looked at ~15 threads on this topic, none of which seem to address my problem.

I have two tables in a strongly typed dataset.  One is a list of Categories with primary key CategoryID.  The second is a list of Items with the foreign key the same CategoryID.  In my dataset, I define the relationship betweeen the two tables as relCtoI.

My wpf form contains a listbox listing the categories and a listbox that is to display those items from the category listbox category that the user picks.  Both listboxs are to be sorted by name.

My pseudo-XAML looks like this:

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
         <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCategories"
                           Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDataSet}, Path=Categories}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CategoryName" />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsItems"
                ....Same thing for the Items with Path=Items ...
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate"
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsItems}, Path=ItemName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource cvsCategories}">
    <....define columns />

    <ListBox Name="lbxCategories"
         Grid.Column="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" />

    <ListBox Name="lbxItems"
         Grid.Column="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=relCtoI}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

The Category listbox works fine but the Item listbox is blank.  What is wrong with my XAML?

Comment: what is `relCtoI`? this code seems to be looking `relCtoI` in `cvsCategories` which is a `CollectionViewSource` as cvsCategories is set as DataContext for the parent element.

Comment: I doubt that the ItemsSource of the second listbox should be `cvsItems` (the CollectionViewSource defined in Window.Resources but appears as not used anywhere). So the code should be `ItemsSource="{StaticResource cvsItems}"`

Comment: @pushpraj relCtoI is defined in my second introductory paragraph.  However, you are right that it is not in the data context.  I'm going to see if this is what I need to fix.

Comment: @King Kong  cvsItems is used in my DataTemplate.  You say that you doubt I should use it but then suggest I use it.  Please clarify.